# php development on Linux - never use /var/ directory

Tags: php, linux

An argument has developed over the appropriate place to store code while developing. I have worked in several Unix development environments now and all had code stored in the /var directory for development purposes, one even for hosting.

I've been accused of making a rookie mistake by using the /var directory for code since /var is variable and code is not temporary. Basically I'm told I should use /usr/ or /home/ for development.

There aren't enough knowledgeable people in the office to settle this argument.

Is there any reason why /var should not be used for code in a) development and b) hosting - assuming a dedicated server is locked down correctly?

Comment: I always use /var/virtual/* guess I'm a bad person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Linux filesystem hierarchy standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) /var is for variable *application* data (databases, caches, logs, etc). As a user, you should do your work in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases your web root is specified to `/var/www`. I don't think that this is a real problem. The most of all Webservers store it there automatically.

Why you shouldn't use the default directory?

In some cases if you have a mangaged server with a lot of users it make sense, that you give permission for all the webserver and files to a home directory. The user can only walk through his own directory and he has all data for his web folder in his home directory.

But if you work on your computer or you have your own root server witch is used by yourself you can use `/var/www` in my opinion. If you would make it really correct you have to use `/srv` to store your application data.

> Site-specific data served by this system, such as data and scripts for web servers, data offered by FTP servers, and repositories for version control systems.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: I agree for /var/www and using the same.